# Get First Tables Inserted Values to Second table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have two queries with transaction scope. I need to insert first tables inserted value to my detail table. In here my `NewsId` in first table is the primary key and an auto-incremented one. I need to insert that id into the second table (`Detail` table)

```
// Some code here

transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

// NewsId is the primary key and auto-incremented. I need to retrieve 
// that value and insert it into the second table 
string query1 = "INSERT INTO ABC(NewsCode, Comment) VALUES (@NewsCode, @Comment)"; 
cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query1);
cmd.Transaction = transaction;

db.AddInParameter(cmd, "NewsCode", DbType.Int32, News.NewsCode);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Comment", DbType.String,News.Comment);

db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, transaction);

foreach (var item in NewsTotal.items)
{
    // I'm going to insert into the `Detail` table and I need the 
    // previously inserted table's NewsId
    string newsItemsQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_T_NewsItems] ([NewsId], [ItemId])
                              VALUES (@NewsId, @Comment)";

    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my answer below

```
transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
string query1 ="Insert Into ABC(NewsCode,Comment) output INSERTED.ID Values (@NewsCode,@Comment)"; 
cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query1);
cmd.Transaction = transaction;
cmd.Connection = con;

db.AddInParameter(cmd, "NewsCode", DbType.Int32, News.NewsCode);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Comment", DbType.String,News.Comment);

int modifiedRowId =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what u can do

```
foreach (var item in NewsTotal.items) { 
string newsItemsQuery = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_T_NewsItems] ([NewsId],[ItemId]) SELECT NewsId, ItemId FROM ABC"; 
 }
```

Comment: This cant be know? because i'm in inside the transaction scope

Comment: OK check out @simonare 's answer. The other option available for you is to create a trigger on the ABC table for INSERT and store the newly generated ids in the other table...